# Wrong encoding on header response Java

Tags: java, rest-assured

I am try to do POST REQUEST to api, let say the API will return a response header in thailand character `10,000 บาท`. after i do the request the response i am getting the header value is `10,000 à¸à¸²à¸`.
Here is the code:

```
RequestSpecification httpRequest = RestAssured.given().header(HeaderKey.appId,header.getAppId());
Response response = httpRequest.post(uri);
String errMessage = response.header("key-to-value-i-want");
System.out.println(errMessage);
```

what's missing from my code? Thanks you

Comment: also i add this ```RestAssured.config = RestAssured.config().encoderConfig(encoderConfig().defaultContentCharset(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));``` on top of code didnt work

Comment: Make sure your console outputs in the correct encoding

Comment: Did you try RestAssured.config().decoderConfig(decoderConfig().defaultContentCharset("UTF-8")); http://static.javadoc.io/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/3.3.0/io/restassured/config/DecoderConfig.html